# Is it possible hyperlink open in non default browser.

Tags: html

can u explain?
Actually my default browser is IE in my system and i have created .html file.But file is open in IE(my default browser). My file is open in IE than after click link to open in another browser.is it possible?
If yes,so please give me syntax.

Thanks & Regards,
Kapeesh

Answer (score 1):

> My file is open in IE than after click link to open in another browser.is it possible?

No, it's impossible.

---

As an alternative you can try to open your file in non-default browser at once (if your page has an URL).

To do so you have to create a shortcut-file to your browser and add file URL as a parameter:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "https://my-site/page.html"
```

This shortcut will open Firefox with your page.

Comment: how to use,plz explain step wise step:"c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "https://my-site/page.html"

Comment: [Right click on desktop -> New -> Shortcut -> ...](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/140443)